Identifying transformer
I’m working on a project and came across this transformer on a circuit board. I’m trying to find the datasheet or any information about its specifications, but I haven’t had much luck with online searches.
Here are the details from the component:
Code: 380GL52P329H

I've attached a photo of the transformer for reference. It has five pins on one side, and it appears to be labeled with "PRIMARY" on the PCB.
Does anyone recognize this part or know where I might find the datasheet?

Probably a custom-wound transformer. It's quite possible no public datasheet exists.

The net is labelled PRIMARY, not the component. As should be obvious given that this is a transformer and as such sitting between a primary side and a secondary side.

There's a Taiwanese company Yuva which labels tranformers similarly: https://en.yuva.com.cn/product/6/. However they seem to print YUVA on them so maybe this one is from someone else. Very likely a custom part either way.

: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404042/where-to-ask-for-help-with-identifying-a-transformer-code-on-a-circuit-boardAlso posted on meta

Looks like it’s from a TV psu.

As an identification question this is fine, just in most cases like this you get no answer - that looks like a custom transformer for a specific purpose and product - likely a TV backlight power supply. It would be a bit more interesting to know what are your plans with the transformer after you have identified it and maybe have a data sheet? Some parameters you can simply measure with an LCR meter, as well as maybe identify nominal frequency and voltages if the PSU still works - although CC backlights may be 100s to 1000s of volts so don't poke your meter or scope there without a guess.
